Problems with secret manager permissions in GCP
I am currently developing a simple code in GCP cloud functions.
The problem is that I need to connect to secret manager to get the api keys.
In jupyter this code works perfectly for me:
def access_secret_version(secret_id):
    project_id = os.getenv("GCP_PROJECT", "My_Project")
    name = f"projects/{project_id}/secrets/{secret_id}/versions/1"
    response = secret_client.access_secret_version(request={"name": name})
    response = response.payload.data.decode("UTF-8")
    return json.loads(response.replace("'", '"'))


ACCESS_TOKEN = access_secret_version("api_key")

But when I deploy it via CI/CD, it throws me this error:
"message": "Function failed on loading user code. This is likely due to a bug in the user code. Error message:   File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>\", line 995, in exec_module
  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File \"/workspace/main.py\", line 40, in <module>
    ACCESS_TOKEN = access_secret_version(\"api_key\")
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File \"/workspace/main.py\", line 35, in access_secret_version
    response = secret_client.access_secret_version(request={\"name\": name})
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File \"/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.12/site-packages/google/cloud/secretmanager_v1/services/secret_manager_service/client.py\", line 1800, in access_secret_version
    response = rpc(
               ^^^^
  File \"/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.12/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/method.py\", line 131, in __call__
    return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File \"/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.12/site-packages/google/api_core/retry/retry_unary.py\", line 293, in retry_wrapped_func
    return retry_target(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File \"/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.12/site-packages/google/api_core/retry/retry_unary.py\", line 153, in retry_target
    _retry_error_helper(
  File \"/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.12/site-packages/google/api_core/retry/retry_base.py\", line 212, in _retry_error_helper
    raise final_exc from source_exc
  File \"/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.12/site-packages/google/api_core/retry/retry_unary.py\", line 144, in retry_target
    result = target()
             ^^^^^^^^
  File \"/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.12/site-packages/google/api_core/timeout.py\", line 120, in func_with_timeout
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File \"/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.12/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py\", line 78, in error_remapped_callable
    raise exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc) from exc
google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403 Permission 'secretmanager.versions.access' denied for resource 'projects/project/secrets/api_key/versions/latest' (or it may not exist).. Please visit https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting for in-depth troubleshooting documentation."

My user and the account service have the same roles, and I have already given the account service admin access to secret manager, secret version, etc.
I have also already verified that the secret key exists in secret manager

Can someone help me with the problem or what permission I should give the account service?

Please update your question so that it is a minimal repro of your issue. This should include the minimal set of code and commands so that other people can attempt to reproduce the error.

The service account that you use does not have the permission. Or you grant the permission on the wrong service account. Can you share the code of your CI/CD to understand how you authenticate ?

Instead of using the python client library to retrieve the secret, you can also pass your secret to your cloud function as an environment variable.
The service account (displayed in the Details tab of your function) will still need to have the roles/secretmanager.secretAccessor role. In your case, the Secret Manager Admin is able to access it if given to the right service account.
